# Stack Navigator doesn't work on Android Device (APK Release)

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I'm using expo to create a React Native app. I use Stack Navigator for my app and it worked perfectly fine on Expo Go as I use 'expo start'. However, when I tried to build the app with EAS, the final product does not function well. I go stuck in the splash icon.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';

// Screens
import HomeStack from './navigations/HomeStack';
import Details from './navigations/screens/Details';
import Results from './navigations/screens/Results';
import TakePicture from './navigations/screens/TakePicture';
import SignUp from './navigations/screens/SignUp';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: "transparent"
  }
}

const App = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
        initialRouteName="HomeStack"
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Results" component={Results} />
        <Stack.Screen name="TakePicture" component={TakePicture} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

if I replace the return code block by

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome to React Native</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
```

it work well on my physical device. I suppose there was a problem with Stack Navigator, but I'm not quite sure.